# Why my date print error using Intl.DateTimeFormat?

Tags: javascript

Why print error, date `-1 day` my date is 2020-03-16, but print 2020-03-15?

> This my code:

```js
let dt = new Date('2020-03-16');
let dt_new = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-BR').format(dt);

console.log(dt_new);
```

Comment: Can you clarify? I see `16/03/2020` printed out.

Comment: Only if you're in a timezone with a negative offset. The date is taken as UTC, then the offset is applied to convert it to local time.

Comment: I'm Brazil, see 15/03/2020, where do i put UTC correct?